# rolling count over group with anchored row criteria

Tags: python-polars

I'm working with the Polars library in Python and I'm trying to create a column expression that generates a "Rolling Count Very Late (> 90 days) by group". I created a prototype of the Polars solution I want in excel:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Invoice Date | Due Date | Date Closed | days | amount | group | Rolling Count Very Late (> 90 days) by group | Rolling Count Very Late (> 90 days) by group formula |
| 2 | 22-Oct-22 | 21-Nov-22 | 1-Mar-23 | 100 | 111 | B | 0 | =COUNTIFS(E$3:E3,">90",G$3:G3,G3,D$3:D3,"<"&B3) |
| 3 | 24-Oct-22 | 23-Nov-22 | 3-Mar-23 | 100 | 150 | B | 0 | =COUNTIFS(E$3:E4,">90",G$3:G4,G4,D$3:D4,"<"&B4) |
| 4 | 31-Oct-22 | 30-Nov-22 | 5-Mar-23 | 95 | 300 | A | 0 | =COUNTIFS(E$3:E5,">90",G$3:G5,G5,D$3:D5,"<"&B5) |
| 5 | 10-Nov-22 | 10-Dec-22 | 2-Feb-23 | 54 | 180 | A | 0 | =COUNTIFS(E$3:E6,">90",G$3:G6,G6,D$3:D6,"<"&B6) |
| 6 | 21-Nov-22 | 21-Dec-22 | 4-Feb-23 | 45 | 220 | B | 0 | =COUNTIFS(E$3:E7,">90",G$3:G7,G7,D$3:D7,"<"&B7) |
| 7 | 4-Dec-22 | 3-Jan-23 | 4-Jan-23 | 1 | 210 | B | 0 | =COUNTIFS(E$3:E8,">90",G$3:G8,G8,D$3:D8,"<"&B8) |
| 8 | 19-Dec-22 | 18-Jan-23 | 20-Jan-23 | 2 | 100 | A | 0 | =COUNTIFS(E$3:E9,">90",G$3:G9,G9,D$3:D9,"<"&B9) |
| 9 | 1-Jan-23 | 31-Jan-23 | 20-Feb-23 | 20 | 200 | B | 0 | =COUNTIFS(E$3:E10,">90",G$3:G10,G10,D$3:D10,"<"&B10) |
| 10 | 22-Jan-23 | 21-Feb-23 | 1-Jun-23 | 100 | 280 | B | 0 | =COUNTIFS(E$3:E11,">90",G$3:G11,G11,D$3:D11,"<"&B11) |
| 11 | 28-Feb-23 | 30-Mar-23 | 2-Apr-23 | 3 | 250 | A | 0 | =COUNTIFS(E$3:E12,">90",G$3:G12,G12,D$3:D12,"<"&B12) |
| 12 | 14-May-23 | 13-Jun-23 | 1-Sep-23 | 80 | 21 | A | 1 | =COUNTIFS(E$3:E13,">90",G$3:G13,G13,D$3:D13,"<"&B13) |
| 13 | 18-Jun-23 | 18-Jul-23 | 1-Oct-23 | 75 | 456 | A | 1 | =COUNTIFS(E$3:E14,">90",G$3:G14,G14,D$3:D14,"<"&B14) |
| 14 | 2-Jul-23 | 1-Aug-23 | 1-Aug-23 | 0 | 320 | B | 3 | =COUNTIFS(E$3:E15,">90",G$3:G15,G15,D$3:D15,"<"&B15) |

#### DataFrame

```py
# pl.Config(tbl_rows=13, fmt_str_lengths=80)

df = (
    pl.read_csv(b"""
Invoice Date|Due Date|Date Closed|days|amount|group|Rolling Count Very Late (> 90 days) by group|Rolling Count Very Late (> 90 days) by group formula
22-Oct-22|21-Nov-22|1-Mar-23|100|111|B|0|=COUNTIFS(E$3:E3,">90",G$3:G3,G3,D$3:D3,"<"&B3)
24-Oct-22|23-Nov-22|3-Mar-23|100|150|B|0|=COUNTIFS(E$3:E4,">90",G$3:G4,G4,D$3:D4,"<"&B4)
31-Oct-22|30-Nov-22|5-Mar-23|95|300|A|0|=COUNTIFS(E$3:E5,">90",G$3:G5,G5,D$3:D5,"<"&B5)
10-Nov-22|10-Dec-22|2-Feb-23|54|180|A|0|=COUNTIFS(E$3:E6,">90",G$3:G6,G6,D$3:D6,"<"&B6)
21-Nov-22|21-Dec-22|4-Feb-23|45|220|B|0|=COUNTIFS(E$3:E7,">90",G$3:G7,G7,D$3:D7,"<"&B7)
4-Dec-22|3-Jan-23|4-Jan-23|1|210|B|0|=COUNTIFS(E$3:E8,">90",G$3:G8,G8,D$3:D8,"<"&B8)
19-Dec-22|18-Jan-23|20-Jan-23|2|100|A|0|=COUNTIFS(E$3:E9,">90",G$3:G9,G9,D$3:D9,"<"&B9)
1-Jan-23|31-Jan-23|20-Feb-23|20|200|B|0|=COUNTIFS(E$3:E10,">90",G$3:G10,G10,D$3:D10,"<"&B10)
22-Jan-23|21-Feb-23|1-Jun-23|100|280|B|0|=COUNTIFS(E$3:E11,">90",G$3:G11,G11,D$3:D11,"<"&B11)
28-Feb-23|30-Mar-23|2-Apr-23|3|250|A|0|=COUNTIFS(E$3:E12,">90",G$3:G12,G12,D$3:D12,"<"&B12)
14-May-23|13-Jun-23|1-Sep-23|80|21|A|1|=COUNTIFS(E$3:E13,">90",G$3:G13,G13,D$3:D13,"<"&B13)
18-Jun-23|18-Jul-23|1-Oct-23|75|456|A|1|=COUNTIFS(E$3:E14,">90",G$3:G14,G14,D$3:D14,"<"&B14)
2-Jul-23|1-Aug-23|1-Aug-23|0|320|B|3|=COUNTIFS(E$3:E15,">90",G$3:G15,G15,D$3:D15,"<"&B15)
""".strip(), 
    separator="|"
    )
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("Invoice Date", "Due Date", "Date Closed").str.to_date("%d-%b-%y")
    )
)
```

This formula counts the number of rows where:

- The 'days' value (column E) is greater than 90,
- The 'group' value (column G) matches the current row's group,
- The 'Date Closed' value (column D) is less than the **current row's** 'Due Date' (column B).

The **current row** piece is the obstacle, not sure how to fit that into the expression
I have a partial solution from a previous related but less complex question, which looks like this:

```
df.with_columns(
    (pl.col("amount") * (pl.col("days") > 90)).cum_sum().over("group").alias("group_sum")
)
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to 'anchor' the Invoice Date for the current row in a Polars friendly way.

Comment: I feel like `.when().then().otherwise()` might be useful for 'anchoring' invoice date to the current row, also there's `df.rolling()`.

Comment: I tried to work the conditional logic angle but couldn't come up with anything, maybe someone else can. I kept getting sucked into purely columnar logic.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current solution. Loop through each row, filter the table down to the criteria I am after and append the row count onto a series. After looping we concatenate as a column to the original df and get the right answers.

It's going to have performance issues on a bigger dataset vs. doing this in a purely columnar/vectorized fashion.

I tried to use Polars as much as I could, but hopefully there's optimizations or possibly an elegant solution

```
import polars as pl

#function to return the rolling count of invoices > 90 days overdue by group
def Rolling90(df: pl.DataFrame, row, days) -> int:
    df = df.filter(
        (pl.col("Invoice Date") < row["Invoice Date"]) &
        (pl.col("Date Closed") < row["Invoice Date"]) &
        (pl.col("group") == row["group"]) &
        (pl.col("days") > days)
    )
    return df.shape[0]



#read in an example dataframe (thanks to whoever did this)

df = (
    pl.read_csv(b"""
Invoice Date|Due Date|Date Closed|days|amount|group|Rolling Count Very Late (> 90 days) by group|Rolling Count Very Late (> 90 days) by group formula
22-Oct-22|21-Nov-22|1-Mar-23|100|111|B|0|=COUNTIFS(E$3:E3,">90",G$3:G3,G3,D$3:D3,"<"&B3)
24-Oct-22|23-Nov-22|3-Mar-23|100|150|B|0|=COUNTIFS(E$3:E4,">90",G$3:G4,G4,D$3:D4,"<"&B4)
31-Oct-22|30-Nov-22|5-Mar-23|95|300|A|0|=COUNTIFS(E$3:E5,">90",G$3:G5,G5,D$3:D5,"<"&B5)
10-Nov-22|10-Dec-22|2-Feb-23|54|180|A|0|=COUNTIFS(E$3:E6,">90",G$3:G6,G6,D$3:D6,"<"&B6)
21-Nov-22|21-Dec-22|4-Feb-23|45|220|B|0|=COUNTIFS(E$3:E7,">90",G$3:G7,G7,D$3:D7,"<"&B7)
4-Dec-22|3-Jan-23|4-Jan-23|1|210|B|0|=COUNTIFS(E$3:E8,">90",G$3:G8,G8,D$3:D8,"<"&B8)
19-Dec-22|18-Jan-23|20-Jan-23|2|100|A|0|=COUNTIFS(E$3:E9,">90",G$3:G9,G9,D$3:D9,"<"&B9)
1-Jan-23|31-Jan-23|20-Feb-23|20|200|B|0|=COUNTIFS(E$3:E10,">90",G$3:G10,G10,D$3:D10,"<"&B10)
22-Jan-23|21-Feb-23|1-Jun-23|100|280|B|0|=COUNTIFS(E$3:E11,">90",G$3:G11,G11,D$3:D11,"<"&B11)
28-Feb-23|30-Mar-23|2-Apr-23|3|250|A|0|=COUNTIFS(E$3:E12,">90",G$3:G12,G12,D$3:D12,"<"&B12)
14-May-23|13-Jun-23|1-Sep-23|80|21|A|1|=COUNTIFS(E$3:E13,">90",G$3:G13,G13,D$3:D13,"<"&B13)
18-Jun-23|18-Jul-23|1-Oct-23|75|456|A|1|=COUNTIFS(E$3:E14,">90",G$3:G14,G14,D$3:D14,"<"&B14)
2-Jul-23|1-Aug-23|1-Aug-23|0|320|B|3|=COUNTIFS(E$3:E15,">90",G$3:G15,G15,D$3:D15,"<"&B15)
""".strip(), 
    separator="|"
    )
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("Invoice Date", "Due Date", "Date Closed").str.to_date("%d-%b-%y")
    )
)

#print the data frame
print(df)


#create a series to hold all of our returned function amounts 
ds = pl.Series("Rolling90cum_count", [], dtype=pl.Int64)
#iterate on all rows in the invoices data frame
for row in df.iter_rows(named=True):
    
    ds.append(pl.Series(name="Rolling", values=[Rolling90(df,row,90)]) )
     
   
#cast the series to a dataframe
ds =ds.to_frame()

#print the ds frame
print(ds)

#attach the new column at the end of the original df
df = pl.concat([df, ds],how="horizontal")

#print the final dataframe
print(df)
```

Outputs:

```
shape: (13, 8)
┌──────────────┬────────────┬─────────────┬──────┬────────┬───────┬────────────────┬───────────────┐
│ Invoice Date ┆ Due Date   ┆ Date Closed ┆ days ┆ amount ┆ group ┆ Rolling Count  ┆ Rolling Count │
│ ---          ┆ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ ---  ┆ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ Very Late (>   ┆ Very Late (>  │
│ date         ┆ date       ┆ date        ┆ i64  ┆ i64    ┆ str   ┆ 90 da…         ┆ 90 da…        │
│              ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆        ┆       ┆ ---            ┆ ---           │
│              ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆        ┆       ┆ i64            ┆ str           │
╞══════════════╪════════════╪═════════════╪══════╪════════╪═══════╪════════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ 2022-10-22   ┆ 2022-11-21 ┆ 2023-03-01  ┆ 100  ┆ 111    ┆ B     ┆ 0              ┆ =COUNTIFS(E$3 │
│              ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆        ┆       ┆                ┆ :E3,">90",G$3 │
│              ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆        ┆       ┆                ┆ :G3,G3…       │
│ 2022-10-24   ┆ 2022-11-23 ┆ 2023-03-03  ┆ 100  ┆ 150    ┆ B     ┆ 0              ┆ =COUNTIFS(E$3 │
│              ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆        ┆       ┆                ┆ :E4,">90",G$3 │
│              ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆        ┆       ┆                ┆ :G4,G4…       │
│ 2022-10-31   ┆ 2022-11-30 ┆ 2023-03-05  ┆ 95   ┆ 300    ┆ A     ┆ 0              ┆ =COUNTIFS(E$3 │
│              ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆        ┆       ┆                ┆ :E5,">90",G$3 │
│              ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆        ┆       ┆                ┆ :G5,G5…       │
│ 2022-11-10   ┆ 2022-12-10 ┆ 2023-02-02  ┆ 54   ┆ 180    ┆ A     ┆ 0              ┆ =COUNTIFS(E$3 │
│              ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆        ┆       ┆                ┆ :E6,">90",G$3 │
│              ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆        ┆       ┆                ┆ :G6,G6…       │
│ 2022-11-21   ┆ 2022-12-21 ┆ 2023-02-04  ┆ 45   ┆ 220    ┆ B     ┆ 0              ┆ =COUNTIFS(E$3 │
│              ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆        ┆       ┆                ┆ :E7,">90",G$3 │
│              ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆        ┆       ┆                ┆ :G7,G7…       │
│ …            ┆ …          ┆ …           ┆ …    ┆ …      ┆ …     ┆ …              ┆ …             │
│ 2023-01-22   ┆ 2023-02-21 ┆ 2023-06-01  ┆ 100  ┆ 280    ┆ B     ┆ 0              ┆ =COUNTIFS(E$3 │
│              ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆        ┆       ┆                ┆ :E11,">90",G$ │
│              ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆        ┆       ┆                ┆ 3:G11,…       │
│ 2023-02-28   ┆ 2023-03-30 ┆ 2023-04-02  ┆ 3    ┆ 250    ┆ A     ┆ 0              ┆ =COUNTIFS(E$3 │
│              ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆        ┆       ┆                ┆ :E12,">90",G$ │
│              ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆        ┆       ┆                ┆ 3:G12,…       │
│ 2023-05-14   ┆ 2023-06-13 ┆ 2023-09-01  ┆ 80   ┆ 21     ┆ A     ┆ 1              ┆ =COUNTIFS(E$3 │
│              ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆        ┆       ┆                ┆ :E13,">90",G$ │
│              ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆        ┆       ┆                ┆ 3:G13,…       │
│ 2023-06-18   ┆ 2023-07-18 ┆ 2023-10-01  ┆ 75   ┆ 456    ┆ A     ┆ 1              ┆ =COUNTIFS(E$3 │
│              ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆        ┆       ┆                ┆ :E14,">90",G$ │
│              ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆        ┆       ┆                ┆ 3:G14,…       │
│ 2023-07-02   ┆ 2023-08-01 ┆ 2023-08-01  ┆ 0    ┆ 320    ┆ B     ┆ 3              ┆ =COUNTIFS(E$3 │
│              ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆        ┆       ┆                ┆ :E15,">90",G$ │
│              ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆        ┆       ┆                ┆ 3:G15,…       │
└──────────────┴────────────┴─────────────┴──────┴────────┴───────┴────────────────┴───────────────┘
shape: (13, 1)
┌───────────────────┐
│ Rolling90cumcount │
│ ---               │
│ i64               │
╞═══════════════════╡
│ 0                 │
│ 0                 │
│ 0                 │
│ 0                 │
│ 0                 │
│ …                 │
│ 0                 │
│ 0                 │
│ 1                 │
│ 1                 │
│ 3                 │
└───────────────────┘
shape: (13, 9)
┌─────────────┬────────────┬─────────────┬──────┬───┬───────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┐
│ Invoice     ┆ Due Date   ┆ Date Closed ┆ days ┆ … ┆ group ┆ Rolling    ┆ Rolling    ┆ Rolling90c │
│ Date        ┆ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ ---  ┆   ┆ ---   ┆ Count Very ┆ Count Very ┆ umcount    │
│ ---         ┆ date       ┆ date        ┆ i64  ┆   ┆ str   ┆ Late (> 90 ┆ Late (> 90 ┆ ---        │
│ date        ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆ da…        ┆ da…        ┆ i64        │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆            │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆ i64        ┆ str        ┆            │
╞═════════════╪════════════╪═════════════╪══════╪═══╪═══════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╡
│ 2022-10-22  ┆ 2022-11-21 ┆ 2023-03-01  ┆ 100  ┆ … ┆ B     ┆ 0          ┆ =COUNTIFS( ┆ 0          │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ E$3:E3,">9 ┆            │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ 0",G$3:G3, ┆            │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ G3…        ┆            │
│ 2022-10-24  ┆ 2022-11-23 ┆ 2023-03-03  ┆ 100  ┆ … ┆ B     ┆ 0          ┆ =COUNTIFS( ┆ 0          │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ E$3:E4,">9 ┆            │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ 0",G$3:G4, ┆            │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ G4…        ┆            │
│ 2022-10-31  ┆ 2022-11-30 ┆ 2023-03-05  ┆ 95   ┆ … ┆ A     ┆ 0          ┆ =COUNTIFS( ┆ 0          │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ E$3:E5,">9 ┆            │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ 0",G$3:G5, ┆            │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ G5…        ┆            │
│ 2022-11-10  ┆ 2022-12-10 ┆ 2023-02-02  ┆ 54   ┆ … ┆ A     ┆ 0          ┆ =COUNTIFS( ┆ 0          │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ E$3:E6,">9 ┆            │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ 0",G$3:G6, ┆            │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ G6…        ┆            │
│ 2022-11-21  ┆ 2022-12-21 ┆ 2023-02-04  ┆ 45   ┆ … ┆ B     ┆ 0          ┆ =COUNTIFS( ┆ 0          │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ E$3:E7,">9 ┆            │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ 0",G$3:G7, ┆            │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ G7…        ┆            │
│ …           ┆ …          ┆ …           ┆ …    ┆ … ┆ …     ┆ …          ┆ …          ┆ …          │
│ 2023-01-22  ┆ 2023-02-21 ┆ 2023-06-01  ┆ 100  ┆ … ┆ B     ┆ 0          ┆ =COUNTIFS( ┆ 0          │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ E$3:E11,"> ┆            │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ 90",G$3:G1 ┆            │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ 1,…        ┆            │
│ 2023-02-28  ┆ 2023-03-30 ┆ 2023-04-02  ┆ 3    ┆ … ┆ A     ┆ 0          ┆ =COUNTIFS( ┆ 0          │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ E$3:E12,"> ┆            │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ 90",G$3:G1 ┆            │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ 2,…        ┆            │
│ 2023-05-14  ┆ 2023-06-13 ┆ 2023-09-01  ┆ 80   ┆ … ┆ A     ┆ 1          ┆ =COUNTIFS( ┆ 1          │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ E$3:E13,"> ┆            │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ 90",G$3:G1 ┆            │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ 3,…        ┆            │
│ 2023-06-18  ┆ 2023-07-18 ┆ 2023-10-01  ┆ 75   ┆ … ┆ A     ┆ 1          ┆ =COUNTIFS( ┆ 1          │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ E$3:E14,"> ┆            │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ 90",G$3:G1 ┆            │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ 4,…        ┆            │
│ 2023-07-02  ┆ 2023-08-01 ┆ 2023-08-01  ┆ 0    ┆ … ┆ B     ┆ 3          ┆ =COUNTIFS( ┆ 3          │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ E$3:E15,"> ┆            │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ 90",G$3:G1 ┆            │
│             ┆            ┆             ┆      ┆   ┆       ┆            ┆ 5,…        ┆            │
└─────────────┴────────────┴─────────────┴──────┴───┴───────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```